# How to outline text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have a Jetpack Compose Text() element that I'd like to outline in black like so [image: this].
Anyone know how to do this?
I've tried using the border() modifier, but that just adds a border around the rectangular area containing the text. I've also tried overlaying two text elements, but that doesn't quite work either.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `1.4.0-alpha01` introduced a `DrawStyle` parameter to `TextStyle` function that enables drawing outlined text.

You can use something like:

```
Text(
    text = "Sample",
    style = TextStyle.Default.copy(
        fontSize = 64.sp,
        drawStyle = Stroke(
            miter = 10f,
            width = 5f,
            join = StrokeJoin.Round
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Before `1.4.0-alpha01` you can use a `Canvas` and the [**`drawIntoCanvas`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/package-summary#drawintocanvas) function.

Something like:

```
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    onDraw = {
                drawIntoCanvas {
                    it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
                        "Sample",
                        0f,
                        120.dp.toPx(),
                        textPaintStroke
                    )
                    it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
                        "Sample",
                        0f,
                        120.dp.toPx(),
                        textPaint
                    )
                }
            }
)
```

with these `Paint`:

```
val textPaintStroke = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
    isAntiAlias = true
    style = android.graphics.Paint.Style.STROKE
    textSize = 64f
    color = android.graphics.Color.BLACK
    strokeWidth = 12f
    strokeMiter= 10f
    strokeJoin = android.graphics.Paint.Join.ROUND
}

val textPaint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
    isAntiAlias = true
    style = android.graphics.Paint.Style.FILL
    textSize = 64f
    color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
}
```

[image]

Comment: do keep in mind using canvas api's directly means we loose many layers of abstraction about placement and measurement a text composable would give us.

Comment: this works but causes the text to go off screen, i've linked a question for it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74372624/compose-drawtext-going-off-screen

Comment: Note that as of `1.4.0-alpha02` setting `drawStyle` to `Stroke` will remove the fill color

Comment: Is there any other option to return fill color other than drawing two same lines on each other? This not working for example for bold style and similar situations. Thanks.

Comment: @Warlock I guess it's only visible like so during preview. In real app, it looks as displayed above

Comment: @polendina Afaik there is no way how to set for example black color to lining and red as fill color (solution with DrawStyle). White color above is only because there is white background used. This ability to have lining and fill color set is very crucial for example for subtitles on different backgrounds.

Comment: The very same question about fill color is asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77146614/how-to-create-a-outlined-text-with-filled-body-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 2):

```
// Creating a outline text
@Composable
fun OutLineText() {

    // Create a Paint that has black stroke
    val textPaintStroke = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = android.graphics.Paint.Style.STROKE
        textSize = 100f
        color = android.graphics.Color.CYAN
        strokeWidth = 12f
        strokeMiter = 10f
        strokeJoin = android.graphics.Paint.Join.ROUND
    }

    // Create a Paint that has white fill
    val textPaint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = android.graphics.Paint.Style.FILL
        textSize = 100f
        color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
    }

    // Create a canvas, draw the black stroke and
    // override it with the white fill
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        onDraw = {
            drawIntoCanvas {
                it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
                        "Hello World",
                        200f,
                        200.dp.toPx(),
                        textPaintStroke
                    )

                    it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
                        "Hello World",
                        200f,
                        200.dp.toPx(),
                        textPaint
                    )
                }
            }
        )
}
```

More detail :
https://gist.github.com/Oleur/ca70cd08f51568a0b870333c15ffbca3
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/overview
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers

Output :

[image]